# Remote desktop is not working - no port 3389 is bound

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

On a Windows7 Pro the remote desktop stopped beeing available.

This is what I checked:

- Port `3389` is not available from extern (`telnet .... 3389` does not work but `telnet .... 445` works)
- `netstat` shows that there is no prozess listening at port 3389
- "Remote Settings" is configured with `Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop ...`
- the `services` (Remote Desktop Services, Remote Desktop Configuration and Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector are running)
- The service `Cryptographic Services` is also started
- windows `firewall is disabled`
- `no third party firewall` is installed
- In the registry is port 3389 configured at `..\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp`
- resetted the ip stack but without success

The customer says that it was working in the past.

**Edit**
In the netstat log (netstat -abn) isn't any entry like

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

and telnet

```
telnet 10.15.100.101 3389
```

does not connect from the localhost and from a remote host in the same network, although the firewall is disabled and other ports (like 445) do listen and do answer.

**Edit2**
Found a similar thread [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/777010-rdp-not-listening-for-connections?page=1#entry-4274879) and the suggestion it may be caused by: [KB2830477](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/kb/2830477). Didn't help.

Comment: Is the Checkbox in the remote settings unchecked where it says only allow connections from computers with NLA ?  also, are you 100% positive the port forward redirects it to the correct IP Address? if you try it locally from another computer can it connect?  What has changed for the customer.

Comment: About NLA: Don't have teamviewer connection any more, can't answer it now. But look at my recent edit. I don't think that the cause on this level or on routing.

Comment: is the "Remote Desktop Services" service running? that spawns the process that should listen on 3389  

 TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           Server01:0             LISTENING
 TermService.  

And if it isnt running do you get any eventlog errors when trying to start it, or eventlog errors after rebooting the system

Comment: Also in the task manager if you check processes and show the column "Command line" you should find a entry under svchost.exe with as commandline "C:\windows\system32\svchost.exe -k termsvcs"

Comment: @Kage Look at my posting: `the services ( .. are running)`. Compared the command lines with another well working W7, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling this updates, remote desktop works again:

[Update for RDP 8.1 KB2923545](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2923545)

[Update for RDP 8.0 KB2592687](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2592687)

This can't be be the final solution but for the moment the customer can work.

Answer (score 0):

To know on which port RDP service is listening, check on following registry path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
```

[How to know/change default RDP listening port](https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/933/How-to-change-the-listening-port-for-Remote-Desktop.html)

Make sure there are restiction of port on your local physical network devices(routers,firewall).

Comment: Thanks, but 3389 is already configured there.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this item just now, exactly the same symptoms, by copying the registry from a working server to my failing server. 
The keys in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server

First made a backup, then copied working keys over failing and done! Not even a restart needed...